# How to get numerical results from HeavisideTheta?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have defined a table `tab = {7.52521, 17.0083, 22.5678, 11.8707, 8.27799}` and a function `F[x_] := tab[[1]]*HeavisideTheta[x] + (tab[[2]] - tab[[1]])*
   HeavisideTheta[x - 20] + (tab[[3]] - tab[[2]])*
   HeavisideTheta[x - 40] + (tab[[4]] - tab[[3]])*
   HeavisideTheta[x - 60] + (tab[[4]] - tab[[5]])*
   HeavisideTheta[x - 80]`.

If I now try to look at the value at 20:

```
In[402]:= F[20]

Out[402]= 7.52521 + 9.48311 HeavisideTheta[0]
```

But the problem is that I need this result to be numerical, because I want to do some more calculations with it. And it is not numerical, because it is at the border of two Heaviside functions. How do I change my definition of function `F` in order to get pass that problem? Or maybe is there a different way to get `F[20]`?
It is not very important value of which Heaviside function it takes (to the left or to the right of 20).

Comment: Try replacing `HeavisideTheta[]` with `UnitStep[]` for numerical evaluations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the whole thing numerically by replacing the Heaviside function with a numerical version. For example:

```
nHeaviside[x_] := If[x < 0, 0, 1]
```

will work. You can choose which value it will assume at zero by changing the  condition to `x <= 0`. Alterantively, the function `Unitstep` does a similar task:

```
nHeaviside2[x_] := UnitStep[x]
```

(Guess who it is suggested this in a comment.)